# How to make a posting list in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dict of tweets in which the key is an identifier and the value is a tuple consisting of the username, tweet, and words in the tweets. I want to create a second dict in which the key is a word and the value the identifiers of the tweets in which this word occurs. The tweets are provided by running a command in the terminal (so stdin).

I have tried many things but have no clue how to get the identifiers in which a word occurs. This is the code I have. It creates a dict with words as keys. The input looks as follows:

```
'1164083099162091520': ('georgevanhouts', 'Is dit waarom Trump waarschijnlijk Groenland wil kopen? In opdracht van Israël? Een Nieuw Kil en Koud Palestina...? #FreePalestine', 'Is dit waarom Trump waarschijnlijk Groenland wil kopen ? In opdracht van Israël ? Een Nieuw Kil en Koud Palestina ...? #FreePalestine')
```

```
    db = {}
    db2 = {}

    for tweet in sys.stdin:
        tweet = tweet.strip()
        tweet = tweet.split("\t")
        db[tweet[0]] = (tweet[1], tweet[2], tweet[3])

        db2[tweet[-1]] = tweet[0]
```

As I said above, the output I want is a dict in which the key is a word and the value the identifiers of tweets in which this word occurs like this:

```
'*word*': '*identifier*' '*identifier*' 'etc'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is identifiers? What does your input look like? What does your expected output look like for that sample input?

Comment: A unique number for one tweet. The input is id user text words, separated by a tab

Comment: Show, don't tell. Please post a working example in the question, with the inputs and outputs

Answer (score 0):

```
db2 = {}
for tweet in sys.stdin:
    tweet = tweet.split("\t")
    indentifiers.append(tweet[0].strip())
    sentences.append(tweet[-1])
    db2[tweet[-1]]=tweet[0].strip()
print(db2)
```

Try this, hopefully this will work

Comment: This results in a dict in which the key is an identifier and the value are the words. I need the key to be one word and the value all the identifiers in which that word occurs.

Comment: Not quite it. This is a dict in which ALL the words are the key and the value is the identifier. I need a dict with as key ONE word, and the value need to be the ALL the identifiers of the tweets in which that word occurs

Comment: Please provide more detail about your input